# Plotly barchart using groupby

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bar-chart

I have a two column dataframe.
There are 3 different codes possible

```
index----| Year-----| Code-----|
0        | 2020     | a        |
1        | 2020     | b        |
2        | 2020     | c        |
3        | 2021     | b        |
4        | 2021     | b        |
```

I want to plot a barchart so the x-axis shows the years , and above each year there should be 3 bars giving the amount of time the code occurs

Comment: What have you tried? Why did it fail?

Comment: I tried: ```pd.pivot_table(data=df,index=['year'], columns='code', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0).plot(kind='bar') ``` but that showed some data from a not mentioned column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) to get the counts and plot with stacked bars:

```
(pd.crosstab(df['Year'], df['Code'])
   .plot.bar(stacked=True)
)
```

output:

[image: stack bars]

Or, with `stacked=False`:

[image]